# Android SoundCloud Sharing fails if user not logged in the SoundCloud App

Tags: android, android-intent, soundcloud, android-sharing

I am trying to add the SoundCloud Sharing functionality to my app. The sharing works fine with the implicit sharing method, assuming user has the SoundCloud app installed  but only if they are logged in to the application. Is it possible to check they are logged in somehow or some workaround to ask them login when the SoundCloud sharing activity pops up?

Thanks!

This is the sharing code:

```
 File audio = new File(sharePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("audio/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(audio));
            //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"),SHARE_SOUND);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"));
```

Comment: Having the same problem.. Did you find solution ?